# intersection of real quadrics in P2

Tags: algebraic-geometry, quadratics, quadratic-forms, projective-space, intersection-theory

Given two real quadrics in $\mathbb P^2$ without common components, then we know that they have at most 4 intersection points.

Suppose that the quadrics are not degenerate (I don't know if this is necessary) and that they are in the form

$$P_1(x,y) = x + Q_1(x,y) \qquad P_2(x,y) = y + Q_2(x,y)$$

where $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are homogeneous of degree 2, and $Q_1(x,y)=Q_2(x,y)=0$ implies $x=y=0$.

Obviously, they have the common solution $(0,0)$ with multiplicity 1, and they do not intersect on the infinite line thanks to the hypothesis on $Q_1,Q_2$.

I know that there is at least an other intersection between the two quadrics, but I don't know how to prove it. Geometrically, I can see it, because the only quadrics are parabolas, circles and hyperboles, and if two of them have a simple intersection, then they have an other one. How can I prove it without doing all the computations case by case?

Comment: $\langle x+a x^2+b x y+c y^2$, $y+a' x^2+b' x y+c' y^2\rangle$ has a lex grobner basis that includes $$(c^2a'^2-bca'b'+acb'^2+b^2a'c'-2aca'c'-abb'c'+a^2c'^2)y^4+(b^2a'-2aca'-abb'-ca'b'+2a^2c'+2ba'c'-ab'c')y^3+(a^2+2ba'-ab'+a'c')y^2+a'y$$ which must have a real solution besides 0.

Comment: not in the case $a'=0$ or when the coefficient of $y^4$ is zero.

Comment: When $a’=0$, $y+\ldots$ is degenerate (a pair of lines). The coefficient of $y^4$ might have a similar consequence, I’ll investigate.

Comment: The coefficient of $y^4$ simplifies to $(ac'-ca')^2+(bc'-cb')(ba'-ab')$, so you're right, more is needed for the complete result.

Comment: Investigating in geogebra the discriminant of $(b^2a'-2aca'-abb'-ca'b'+2a^2c'+2ba'c'-ab'c')y^2+(a^2+2ba'-ab'+a'c')y+a'$ when $(ac'-ca')^2+(bc'-cb')(ba'-ab')=0$ I found $$\langle x-0.9x^2-3.15xy-2.25y^2,y+5x^2+0xy-5y^2\rangle$$ which seems to be a counter-example.

Comment: But $$-0.9x^2-3.15xy-2.25y^2=5x^2-5y^2=0$$ has a common component $y+x=0$.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Write a proper answer

Answer (score 1):

You can show that the pencil of conics must contain a degenerate line pair.  This follows from the generalized eigenvalue problem involving your two 3x3 conic matrix representations.

$$
det(P_1 + λP_2)=0
$$

This is a cubic equation for your pencil of quadrics.  This is guaranteed to have at least one real solution for λ.  Such a solution is a degenerate conic, a pair of lines, and one of the lines in the pair must intersect at the origin and then must also intersect the quadric again on its way "out".  Such a line is guaranteed to have two real intersection points if you know it has one real intersection point.

All full rank quadrics in P2 are projectively equivalent to a circle.  So if a line goes in, it must go out.

Answer (score 0):

What if you have $f(x)=-3x^2$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{2}x^2$? Then you have a single intersection at $(0,0)$ but no intersections anywhere else.

Comment: your conics intersect at $(0,y)$ for every $y$..

Comment: @Exodd, I guess I don't understand the notation in your original question. But your comment doesn't make sense to me; how can the functions intersect at $(0, y)$ for all $y$ when each function only crosses the $x$-axis at $(0, 0)$? I mean, neither function includes the point $(0,1)$.

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to explain: my conics have two variables $x,y$, for example $x^2+2y^2-xy+x$, and I'm looking for the intersections of their zero sets.

Comment: Also, in addition to the origin ([0,0,1]) those two parabolas intersect at infinity at the point [1,0,0] in P2